# 28: No space left on device ubuntu touch

Tags: partitioning, ubuntu-touch, disk-usage

```
I have not space on my partition..

When I put: sudo apt install ....

system say: 
Error escribiendo al fichero de salida - write (28: No space left on device) Error escribiendo a archivo - write (28: No space left on device)


XXXX@ubuntu-phablet:/$ df -h
Filesystem                     Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                           2,7G  812K  2,7G   1% /dev
tmpfs                          560M  1,5M  558M   1% /run
/dev/sda21                     111G   47M  106G   1% /userdata
/dev/disk/by-partlabel/system  2,9G  2,9G     0 100% /
/dev/loop0                     533M  459M   63M  89% /android
tmpfs                          2,8G  4,0K  2,8G   1% /etc/fstab
none                           4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                          2,8G   20K  2,8G   1% /tmp
none                           5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none                           2,8G  176K  2,8G   1% /run/shm
none                           100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
tmpfs                          2,8G     0  2,8G   0% /media
cgmfs                          100K     0  100K   0% /run/cgmanager/fs
tmpfs                          2,8G     0  2,8G   0% /var/lib/openvpn/chroot/tmp
tmpfs                          2,8G     0  2,8G   0% /var/lib/sudo
/dev/sde47                     993M  899M   78M  93% /android/vendor
tmpfs                          2,8G     0  2,8G   0% /mnt
/dev/sde46                     192M  163M   30M  85% /android/vendor/firmware_mnt
/dev/sde44                      28M   25M  2,5M  91% /android/vendor/dsp
/dev/sda14                      28M  4,0M   23M  15% /mnt/vendor/persist
/dev/sde24                      64M  704K   64M   2% /android/vendor/bt_firmware
tmpfs                          560M   52K  559M   1% /run/user/32011
tmpfs                          560M     0  560M   0% /run/user/0


I saw this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vbZsrXoNZXI

but for me dissapear this Mounted point "/" 


sudo parted /dev/sda
GNU Parted 3.2
Using /dev/sda
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print free                                                       
Model: SAMSUNG KLUDG4U1EA-B0C1 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 123GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 4096B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
        12,3kB  24,6kB  12,3kB  Free Space
 1      24,6kB  41,0kB  16,4kB               switch
 2      41,0kB  73,7kB  32,8kB               ssd
 3      73,7kB  524kB   451kB                bk01
 4      524kB   786kB   262kB                bk02
 5      786kB   1049kB  262kB                bk03
 6      1049kB  1573kB  524kB                keystore
 7      1573kB  2097kB  524kB                frp
 8      2097kB  4194kB  2097kB               bk04
 9      4194kB  8389kB  4194kB               misc
10      8389kB  16,8MB  8389kB               logfs
11      16,8MB  33,6MB  16,8MB               oops
12      33,6MB  50,3MB  16,8MB               devinfo
13      50,3MB  67,1MB  16,8MB               bk05
14      67,1MB  134MB   67,1MB  ext4         persist
15      134MB   201MB   67,1MB  ext4         persistbak
16      201MB   268MB   67,1MB               logdump
17      268MB   403MB   134MB                minidump
18      403MB   1275MB  872MB   ext4         cust
19      1275MB  1342MB  67,1MB               recovery
20      1342MB  1611MB  268MB   ext4         cache
21      1611MB  123GB   121GB   ext4         userdata
        123GB   123GB   1040kB  Free Space



Could I expand the partition? how would it be done?
```

Comment: Ubuntu Touch is now called [*Lomiri*](https://lomiri.com/) and supported by UBports.

Comment: And regrettably Ubuntu Touch  is no longer supported at Ask Ubuntu.